# transfer of electricity through electromagnetic waves

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-radiation

Is it possible to transfer electricity from one place to another without the help of physical wires.

Comment: I meant to say that is it possible to convert the electricity into electromagnetic waves then transfer these waves from one part of the world to another and then convert back these electromagnetic waves into electricity at the receiver point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Examples

- RFID tags.
- Toothbrush chargers.
- Shining a torch at a solar cell.
- Crystal radio.

You may be thinking of Tesla's [World System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wireless_System) "for the transmission of electrical energy without wires".

As a means of transmitting significant amounts of power over long distances, all the above are less efficient and/or less practical than building installing and maintaining expensive metal wires and cables.